# JMeter - Start thread groups in parallel and in sequence to other thread groups

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I would create a test plan in JMeter that starts 3 thread group simultaneously, and, when they are finished, starts other 3 thread group.
It can be possible in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with Scheduler settings - just add Duration and Start-up delay in Thread Group (Set duration of first 3 TGs and set delay for second 3 TGs)

Comment: I haven't the duration of a thread group, it just performs some tasks, so the duration can be variable